# Imitating a static method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is this the correct way to imitate a static method in Python? Does Python allow static methods?

```
class C(object):

    def show(self,message):
        print("The message is: {}".format(message))

m = "Hello World!"
C.show(C,message=m)
```

`The message is: Hello World!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`@classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
@classmethod
def show(cls, message):
        print("The message is: {}".format(message))
```

The difference between a `classmethod` and a `staticmethod` is that the latter knows nothing about its enclosing class, whereas the former does (via the `cls` argument). A `staticmethod` can just as easily be declared outside the class.

If you don't want `show()` to know anything about `C`, either use `@staticmethod` or declare `show()` outside of `C`.

Comment: On classmethods, better use `cls` instead of `self`.

Comment: This is incorrect. See @glglgl answer.

Comment: @JHarris Ist is another valid way to do so; it will work as well. Mine is cleaner, however.

Comment: It works sure, but it's not right ;)

Comment: @JHarris I don't agree.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic translation of a static method from other languages is usually a module-level method.

```
def show(message):
    print("The message is: {}".format(message))
```

The answers telling you that python has `@staticmethod`s are correct, and also misleading: it is usually correct to just use a module-level function.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`@staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```
@staticmethod
def show(message):
    print("The message is: {}".format(message))
```

Comment: Sorry, @arshajii, could not resist to imitate your answer 1:1 :-)

Comment: It all depends if they're after a C++ style static method aka, a Python class method, or a Python static method, which is rarely of any use

Comment: I guess @JonClements is right, we're missing some context. Static methods are good for grouping functionality which doesn't operate on an instance. See Raymond Hettinger's class tools talk from PyCon for some extra stuff on that.

Comment: Downvote? Why? It is definitely not complete wrong, as far as we can tell by now.

Comment: @GLES And if someone downvotes your question, you downvote all your answers? Wow.

Comment: Who said so? I upvoted all the answers including comments.

Comment: @GLES Your comment sounded like it. If I was wrong, I am sorry.

Comment: No worries :) The proof - http://postimg.org/image/6fa5gocf3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the decorator `@classmethod`. That won't pose a problem. Additionally

> if a class method is called for a derived class, the derived class
>   object is passed as the implied first argument (http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

```
class C1(object):

    @classmethod
    def show(cls,message):
        print("[{}] The message is: {}".format(cls,message))

class C2(C1):
    pass

m = "Hello World!"
C2.show(message=m)
# vs. C1.show(message=m) with output [<class '__main__.C1'>] The message is: Hello World!
```

`[<class '__main__.C2'>] The message is: Hello World!`